# I can remove everything except this one thing in regex: "co-". Not sure how to deal with the dash

Tags: python, regex

I have a column of counties, that are prepended by variations of `co`, `co. ,`Co.`,`co-` etc and I want to get rid of these and just leave the county name (in this case, Cork).

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'area':['Co Cork','Co. Cork','Co-Cork','Co- Cork','co. Cork','county cork']})
print(x)

          area
0      Co Cork
1     Co. Cork
2      Co-Cork
3     Co- Cork
4     co. Cork
5  county cork
```

This is what I have tried, and have removed most of them, except the third one, with the dash `-` which is joined to the word `Cork`.

```
x['fixed']=(x['area'].str.replace('co\s+', '', case=False)
              .str.replace('co.\s+', '', case=False)
              .str.replace('county\s+', '', case=False)
              .str.replace('co\-\s+ | co-$', '', case=False)
              .str.replace('co\.\s+', '', case=False)
              .str.replace('\W', '')
              .str.title())

print(x)

          area   fixed
0      Co Cork    Cork
1     Co. Cork    Cork
2      Co-Cork  Cocork
3     Co- Cork    Cork
4     co. Cork    Cork
5  county cork    Cork
```

I used the dollar sign `$` here: `.str.replace('co\-\s+ | co-$', '', case=False)` to get strings that end in `co-`. I thought that would remove it. But I guess it's not working because it's a substring?

So, what extremely obvious thing am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not use spaces around `|`, use `r'co-(?:\s+)?$'` instead of `'co\-\s+ | co-$'`

Comment: Your second one is `co.\s+`, are you sure? Do you mean to match any char after `co`? Or do you want to match any non-word char?

Comment: this one `co.\s+` I am looking for a`co.` followed by a space. I want to remove `'co. '`

Comment: Is there any time that there could be a `co-` anywhere in the middle of the string that should *not* be removed? If so, what is the rule that tells you whether to remove that `co-`?

Comment: Hint: you mentioned `$`, for strings that "end in" something. Is there a similar common relationship between all the strings you want to remove?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  I didn't see your question, and it's hours later now. But anyway, all the variations of `co` are at the start of the string. I guess that's the common relationship.

Comment: So, the trick is that `^` anchors to the start of the string. So then we just need a pattern that matches all the things that should be removed. So those things start (case-insensitively) with `co`, so we have `^co` so far... now what? :) Just trying to give you a general intuition for how you figure out the regex you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
x['area'].str.replace(r'(?i)\bco(?:\b[-.]?|unty)\s*', '').str.title()
```

Output:

```
>>> x['area'].str.replace(r'(?i)\bco(?:\b[-.]?|unty)\s*', '').str.title()
0    Cork
1    Cork
2    Cork
3    Cork
4    Cork
5    Cork
Name: area, dtype: object
```

The `(?i)\bco(?:\b[-.]?|unty)\s*` [pattern matches](https://regex101.com/r/vQf14E/1):

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `\b` - word boundary
- `co` - a substring
- `(?:\b[-.]?|unty)` - a non-capturing group matching

  - `\b[-.]?` - word boundary and then an optional `-` or `.`
  - `|` - or
  - `unty` - a `unty` string
- `-\s*` - `-` and 0+ whitespaces.

Comment: Some `co` remain though. From index 2 and 3.

Comment: And what if the `co.` is joined to the word `Cork`? Like `Co.Cork`

Comment: @SCool Do you mean `Cocork` should be `Cork`? Just a sec

Comment: Yes, I am trying to remove these prefixes. `co.` and `co-` and `co. ` etc. Cork could be stack overflow. Eg. `Co. stackoverflow`. I just need to remove these variations of `co`

Comment: you changed `Co-Cork` to  `Cocork`. What I was trying to do was remove all the `co-` etc. so I can be left with `Cork`. If it was `Co.Killkenny` I will try to remove `co.` to make `Kilkenny`. etc.

Comment: @SCool I think I got it, please check the latest update. Note that probably, `[-.]?` can be enanced if you replace it with `\W?`

Comment: That's absolutely perfect and much more complicated, but also shorter than mine. It works very well. I will have to study this for a while. Thanks for the quick reply. My `\W` was there because some data has numbers in it which i tried to remove. Example `New3 York 1`. I will try and figure that one out. Thanks again